# Cannot use a string in Django ManyToManyField through value

Tags: python, django, django-models

(Apologies if I'm missing some critical info to help diagnose this -- I'm new to Python and Django.)

Django complains when I try to use a string in my ManyToManyField through attribute:

```
File "/vagrant/flamingo_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1366, in _check_relationship_model
  for f in through._meta.fields:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Usage:

```
class Voter(models.Model):
  # ...
  addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='voter_addresses', through_fields=('voter_id', 'address_id'))
```

The error goes away if I create a Through model:

```
class VoterAddress(models.Model):
  voter_id = models.ForeignKey(Voter)
  address_id = models.ForeignKey(Address)

  class Meta:
    db_table = 'voter_addresses'
```

But of course then it complains that Voter hasn't been defined--and I can't simply change the order, or else VoterAddress won't have been defined either.

And in every single example I have seen the basic string version used. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the name passed to your `through`

```
addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='VoterAddress')
```

It has to be the exact name of the *custom* `throughmodel`

You will not be required to create a `throughmodel` if you do not pass the `through` argument. Django will create and manage one for you

Comment: Nice one, Moses (+1)

Comment: Does this mean the through parameter takes a class name, not a table name?

Comment: class name / model name. Yes. You do not have much concerns about table name management with Django, except you explicitly want to change names.

Comment: I'm connecting to someone else's database so I have no control over the table names, and the tables were not named with python/django in mind.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your ordering issue you can give a string value to the `ForeignKey` class.

```
class VoterAddress(models.Model):
    voter_id = models.ForeignKey("Voter")
    address_id = models.ForeignKey("Address")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'voter_addresses'
```

This is a way to define foreignkeys to Models that haven't been defined in the file yet.
If you change this Django won't complain that `Voter hasn't been defined`.

Comment: This will likely work, but I'm going to hold out for an answer to why I can't simply use the join table name in the ManyToMany field.

Comment: Why does your `'address__id'` have two underscores

Comment: Typo. Fixed. Thanks.